# CruiseControl.Net + SSL

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

So just installed cruisecontrol.NET on my PC and I am using VisualSVN for the SVN hosting with https:// and a 'dummy' certificate. All this is on my local PC.

The problem is that when I try and run cruisecontrol.NET - it keeps giving me "Server certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted"

Im not sure how to make cruisecontrol.NET accept that the cert is OK ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run certmgr.msc as the user who your CCNET service is running under.  Then, add your SSL cert to the "Personal" cerfiticates in there.  The cert will then be trusted.

But it sounds like you also issued the cert to the wrong hostname.  So, to fix that, examine your certificate and see what hostname you assigned it for.  My guess is that you assigned it to "localhost" and you're referring to your CCNET server by its network name, or vice-versa.  You should make sure that whatever URL CCNet is going to matches the hostname on your certificate.  So you will either need to change the machine name you're connecting to in CCNET, or you will have to re-issue your certificate.

Comment: hi :) thx for the response. so I have the VisualSVN cert via :c\program files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\Certs - which is server.pem. So add this to the personal certificates?

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to add this to the Personal Cert store.  Make sure you're adding the cert to the Personal Cert store of the user that is running CruiseControl.NET though.  That's super-important.  And like I said, make sure your hostnames match!  (In fact, the hostname issue might be the only thing that's wrong here)

Comment: ok great - ill give it a try. how to exactly examine where the hostname was assigned to in VisualSVN ? or you mean just the address of the SVN itself ?

Comment: It's the hostname that you use inside of CCNET to connect to VisualSVN.  This is most likely in your <svn> block in CruiseControl.  Google around for how to examine your certificate's contents.  You might be able to open the cert with Windows Explorer, but I don't know for sure with PEM files.

Comment: yeah no idea in the end :S - i just launched interactive and it seems to work. thx again

Comment: "It's the hostname that you use inside of CCNET to connect to VisualSVN" Not quite, it's actually the account used to run the CruiseControl.NET Server windows service. Check the Log On tab in services.msc