# SSL of SVN Not trusted by CCNet Server

Tags: svn, ssl, cruisecontrol.net

We have a windows server 2008 R2 box which houses our subversion and Cruise Control servers. I am trying to get the first build running on this box as part of an overall migration project to this server. But when running the build, it fails stating that the certificate is not trusted.

originally this was due to the host names not matching the collabnet supplied certificate of course was at odds with our server. we remedied this by creating a new certificate authority and certificate for the server and installing the newly created certificate, this works fine. from a web browser as there is now no conflict.

But the CCNet build continues to fail. To try and counteract this I have logged onto the server as the service account user we created to run Cruise Control and checked out a project from the repository accepting the certificate when requested, this also did not clear rthe problem.

Does anyone have any ideas what this could be. I usually include heaps of code but not really sure what I can include other than the error message below.

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://ourserver/svn/Repo01/ourproject/trunk' svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'hhttps://ourserver/svn/Repo01/ourproject/trunk': Server certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted (https://ourserver) . Process command: svn log https://ourserver/svn/Repo01/ourproject/trunk -r "{2013-01-21T10:11:35Z}:{2013-01-21T10:13:06Z}" --verbose --xml --no-auth-cache --non-interactive at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo processInfo) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Svn.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModificationsWithLogging(ISourceControl sc, IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModifications(ISourceControl sourceControl, IIntegrationResult lastBuild, IIntegrationResult thisBuild) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
```

Comment: I believe this question is about the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266138/cruisecontrol-net-ssl